# Vehicle overheating

Tags: chevrolet, overheating, trailblazer

I have a 2004 Chevy Trailblazer that was run hot. We replaced all the obvious, radiator, water pump, Thermostat, radiator cap, overflow tank, and the fan clutch. It still overheats, and at the first start up in the morning it shoots up water through the radiator. HELP

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: _I have a 2004 Chevy Trailblazer that was run hot_  Are you saying it's running hot, or that you ran it hot at one point (and thereby possibly severely overheating it)? If the latter - you may very well have a blown head gasket. The compression of the engine might be forcing the coolant out.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you didn't mention was the coolant hoses. If they are are blocked or kinked in any way that would cause overheating. Is the coolant mixed to the correct concentration and the right quantity ? When changing everything in the cooling system you most times get air pockets in the cooling jacket that need to be bled out. These air pockets cause hot spots and interfere with the flow of coolant leading to overheating. The water that is spurting out of your radiator is the trapped air inside trying to come out. These air pockets also decrease the volume of the coolant. Run the engine with the radiator cap off and keep adding water and coolant and eventually the air bubbles with expel themselves then top up the fluid and replace the cap. BE CAREFUL
It is going to be hot.